# При стилизации QCheckBox в Qt Designer, пропадает галочка

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

Пытаюсь стилизовать `QCheckBox`. Но при этом у `QCheckBox` пропадает галочка.

Как ее вернуть, но при этом стилизовать `QCheckBox`.

```
QCheckBox::indicator {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.5, x2:1, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(48, 48, 48, 230));
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
}

QCheckBox{ 
    font:18px;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QCheckBox{ 
    font:18px;
}
QCheckBox::indicator {
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 205, 0);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 205, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 пожалуйста.